# How to extract characters within brackets in Google Bigquery? [SQL]

Tags: sql, regex, split, google-bigquery, extract

I am attempting to only extract the values within the parentheses. I have attempted the following:

```
SPLIT(name, ' ')[OFFSET(1)]
```

But thats runs into issues when there are multiple words in the name

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select *,
  regexp_extract(name, r'\((.*?)\)')
from your_table
```